# How can I make an instance of UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, single-instance, appdelegate

In my first iphone app I have a NavigationController.
How can I define in AppDelegate an instance of UINavigationController and set that for my default navigation controller?

in .h:

```
@interface DefaultTableAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    //...
    UINavigationController *myNavigationController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *myNavigationController;
//...
@end
```

in .m:

```
#import "DefaultTableAppDelegate.h"
#import "SHKConfiguration.h"
#import "SKCustomConfigurator.h"
#import "DefaultTableViewController.h"

@implementation DefaultTableAppDelegate 

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize myNavigationController = _myNavigationController;
//...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...

    DefaultTableViewController *main = [[DefaultTableViewController alloc]init];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:main];

    myNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.window addSubview:myNavigationController.view];

    self.window.rootViewController=myNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

CustomNavigationItem subclass of UINavigationItem:

in .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DefaultTableAppDelegate.h"

@interface CustomNavigationItem : UINavigationItem
{
    //...
    DefaultTableAppDelegate *myDelegate;
} 
@end
```

in .m:

```
#import "CustomNavigationItem.h"
#import "DefaultTableViewController.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationItem
//...

-(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender
{
    myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //...
    [myDelegate.myNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}

@end
```

Here is a screenshot from my storyboard: http://postimage.org/image/sv6elwmcz/

The TabBarController's NavigationItem's class is set to CustomNavigationItem, and the NavigationItem's right button has the -(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h" //Or whatever you named your viewController

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc]init];

   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];// Override point for customization after application launch.
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:main];

nav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 [self.window addSubview:nav.view];

self.window.rootViewController=nav; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

}

**EDIT**
without using appDelegate 
do this:

```
-(IBAction)actionApply:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and remove`UINavigationController *myNavigationController;`
 from your `appDelegate.h`

Comment: Thank you for this code, it looks good, but my app don't work with it. After splash screen appears an empty black screen and do nothing... I'm using latest Xcode, ARC, and the default navigation controller was created with storyboard. The MainViewController is the class assigned for the first view, where "starts" the navigation controller, right?

Comment: thanks, but you forgot that CustomNavigationItem is a subclass of UINavigationItem, so I don't have self.navigationController in my action. that's the problem...